# VideoCapture will not open the video

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I am trying to open a video and write it to a location:

```c
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "iostream"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string videoName = "KorExp3.avi";
    VideoCapture video(videoName);

    Mat frame;

    video >> frame;

    VideoWriter w("D:/w.avi", CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2'), 30, frame.size(), true);
    while (true) {
        video >> frame;
        imshow("frame", frame);
        w << frame;
    }
    w.release();

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

In debug mode, while hovering the mouse on `video` it says:

> Information not available, no symbols loaded for opencv_world340d.dll

I have copied this dll file and the video file to the same location of **.exe**, but still same thing happens. I also tried the absolute path to the video `string videoName = "D:\\KorExp3.avi";` but didn't work.

How can I capture a video and write it to a location using openCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the directory of the video instead of moving the video to the project location andthe error was solved:

```c
string videoName = "D:\\KorExp3.avi";
while (true) {
    video >> frame;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you generate (compile) OpenCV with debug symbols?? 
This is a sample (and simple) code to record a video file using OpenCV...
I am using Qt (5.5.1 and upper) on Linux, but this is doesn't matter...
It will work in every OS...

```
void MainWindow::on_Rec_Click()
{
        QString szNome = QString("%1/%2-%3-M.mp4").arg(szPath).arg(szCamIndex).arg(obAgora.toString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
        qDebug() << szNome;

        char    szCPath[2048];
        strcpy(szCPath, szNome.toStdString().c_str());
        qDebug() << "Path: " << szCPath; 
        MakePath(szCPath, inIndice+1); // If the path does not exist...
        SaveEventToDB(szNome, inIndice+1, obAgora, 0); // Register event in DB
        qDebug() << m_Capture[inIndice - 1] << " / " << inIndice;
        cv::Size S = cv::Size((int) m_Capture[inIndice]->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),    // Acquire input size
                              (int) m_Capture[inIndice]->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

        qDebug() << S.width << " / " << S.height;

        int ex = cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M','P','4','2');
        qDebug() << ex;

        double dlFrameRate = m_Capture[inIndice]->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
        qDebug() << dlFrameRate;

        m_Output = new cv::VideoWriter(szNome.toStdString(), ex, dlFrameRate, S, true);
        qDebug() << "Object cv::VideoWriter created.";

        m_OutputFile = szNome;
        m_inTimerID = startTimer(1000 / dlFrameRate);
}

void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if(m_inActualView != 0) {
        cv::Mat image;
        *m_Capture[m_inActualView] >> image;

        if(m_Output) {
            if(m_Output->isOpened()) {
                *m_Output << image;
            }
        }
        cv::flip( image,image, 0);

        // Show the image
        m_Ui->openCVViewer->showImage( image );
    }
}
```